# Adding combined fragments in UML Designer for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, uml, sequence, sequence-diagram, uml-designer

I'm using the latest version of UML Designer (7.1) for Eclipse. I have to create a Sequence Diagram, but in the palettes there are no combined Fragments. All I have are actors and sync/async messages. In some tutorials I've seen seen palettes with comb. fragments.. But I don't have them. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combined fragments are not implemented in UML Designer and there is no plan to implement them at the moment.

As UML Designer is based on Eclipse Sirius, it is possible to do it and maybe you saw the same kind of features in another Sirius based modeler.

If you are interested in sponsoring us to implement this feature do not hesitate to comment the existing issue :
https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/175